# Scrapy queue same spider with different variable

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of url ending I want to crawl in a .csv file like so:

```
run

123

124

125
```

I want to run all of these in one spider in an orderly queue. So run MySpider with 123, after its complete, run MySpider with 124, and soo on.

Something like:

```
process=CrawlerProcess()
with open('run.csv') as rows:
 for row in DictReader(rows):
  process.crawl(numbers(row['run']))
process.start()
```

But run one after another. And I need to pass the variable row['run'] from the .csv file into the spider to get used.

Here is a sample spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
 low=row['run']
 high=row['run']+1000
 self.start_urls=['http://www.canada411.ca/res/%s/' % page for page in xrange(low,high)]
 def parse(self,response):
  yield{
   'Number': row['run'],
   'Name': SCRAPPED
  }

process=CrawlerProcess()
with open('run.csv') as rows:
 for row in DictReader(rows):
  process.crawl(numbers)
process.start()
```

Comment: You cant scrape URLs in order in Scrapy ... impossible

Comment: Yes you can. I just found out how.

Comment: Does that crawl URLs in specific order? I dont think so.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I wanted to run my spider for each "code" in my csv file. From there, the spider runs through a series of urls based on that code.

Comment: I see. So you found a solution or not? I see you have posted an answer below. Does that work for you?

Comment: @MaciekSemik: Please share your solution.

Comment: Its below in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging()
runner=CrawlerRunner()
@defer.inlineCallbacks

def crawl():
 with open('run.csv') as rows:
  for row in DictReader(rows):
   yield runner.crawl(numbers,areacode=row['area code'])
 reactor.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the run_spider() from scrapydo package to achieve this
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapydo/0.2.2